# Precompilation failing heroku even when using user-env-compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, precompile

I'm trying to push up to Heroku, but I'm getting this error:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I'm using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0. I've seen posts that say I should enable user-env-compile so that my environment variables are used in Heroku slug compilation, so I did this:

`heroku labs:enable user-env-compile --app <my app's name>`

I've also disabled it and re-enabled it. But, I'm still getting the same error. What could be the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the rails_12factor gem as detailed at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4

Comment: also - you definitely don't have to resort to precompiling locally before pushing.

Comment: @JohnBeynon I am using the rails_12factor gem; it's included under the production section of my Gemfile. Right, I'm trying to not have to compile locally.

Comment: Were you able to solve this, @Jack? I have two environments: staging and production. The Staging one works finally after enabling and disabling multiple times. However, the production is not working still.

Comment: @YosepKim I could not get precompilation working. I believe it ended up being one of my gems called Redactor needed some environment variables because I took that gem out and things worked fine. Setting those variables in Heroku config didn't work. :/ Sorry I don't have a good solution.

Comment: @Jack, thank you for your answer! Yeah, I haven't been able to fix this problem yet. I am basically now using the Staging environment as Production. It looks like the Heroku lab thing is unstable. Thank you again for reaching back out.

Answer (score 1):

It's less than ideal, but I was having a similar issue using Rails 4 on Heroku and resorted to pre-compiling locally using: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

If you want to avoid having your compiled assets in `master`, you could create a deploy branch, pre-compile, commit, push to heroku and then destroy.

Comment: Do you have to specify the Heroku database URL, table name, username, and password in the database.yml when doing `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: What's the importance of setting RAILS_ENV=production?

Comment: Just discover the importance: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally. Without this heroku doesn't detect the locally compiled assets. I also had to change my database.yml to include a production database.